# How to Unify a Type Implementing an Interface and the Same Type as a Parameter?

Tags: f#

Given the following types

```
type IDocPartX<'delta, 'pures> = 
    abstract member ToDelta: 'pures -> 'delta
    abstract member ToPure: 'delta -> 'pures
    abstract member Validate: 'pures -> Option<'pures>

type InitX<'a>(v:'a) =
    member this.Value = v

type Foo<'a> = {value: 'a} with
    interface IDocPartX<Foo<int>, Foo<string>> with 
        member this.ToDelta x = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
        member this.ToPure x = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
        member this.Validate x = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

this function

```
let inline ValidateInitX(x:InitX<IDocPartX<'d,'p>>) = 
    let r = x.Value
    let d = r :?> 'd
    let o = 
        d
        |> r.ToPure
        |> r.Validate
    match o with
    | Some v -> r.ToDelta v |> Init |> Some
    | _ -> None
```

and this values

```
let a = InitX {value = 1}
let b = ValidateInitX a
```

why is the value `a` not recognized to be of `InitX<IDocPartX<'a, 'b>>`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit of SRTPs magic on the function definition will do the trick

```
let inline ValidateInitX<'d, 'p when 'd :> IDocPartX<'d,'p>>(x:InitX<'d>) = 
    let r = x.Value
    let o = 
        r
        |> r.ToPure
        |> r.Validate
    match o with
    | Some v -> r.ToDelta v |> Init |> Some
    | _ -> None
```